# how to display literal control in specific color

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a survey style page that I want to setup controls in case a question is not answered I have attached the following code to a Literal. I would like to know if I can change the color of the text inside the literal to Red.

```
if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem == null)
   {
       string showmsg = "Please Answer Question";
       Literal1.Text = showmsg;
   }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Supply it HTML as,

```
string showmsg = "<span style='color:red'> Please Answer Question </span>";
```

That will be rendered as multiple spans. It's better if you use other controls which support color change from the C# code. Like `Label` and use its property [Label.ForeColor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.forecolor.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I would change it to a Label.  At that point, you have the option of using CSS and the .CssClass property, or just straight ASP.NET using the ForeColor property.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to change in Code Behind, do same thing in Design. But, here `span` is outside `Literal` tag:

```
<span style="color:red"><asp:Literal ID="litmessage" runat="server"></asp:Literal></span>
```

It works too and no need to upload `bin` files again, if your application is LIVE!

Comment: Nice workaround. Lame that Literal doesn't support style.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Label control instead which has ForeColor property that you can set

```
<asp:Label ID="lblMessage" ForeColor="Gren" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
```

In code behind

```
lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
```